# How to connect to MySQL db from python 3 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, mysql

I am following this guide so that I can can install the MySQL connector for python 3.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501080/how-to-connect-to-mysql-db-from-python-3-on-ubuntu-16

Unfortunately when I typed:

```
(env) pip install mysqlclient

Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.4MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /home/hugh/SAT/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sbgaxask/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpqgsp3qwwpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/home/hugh/SAT/env/include/python3.5m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c:32:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /home/hugh/SAT/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sbgaxask/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d4xggqn_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hugh/SAT/env/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/home/hugh/SAT/env/include/python3.5m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:32:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/tom/SAT/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-sbgaxask/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-d4xggqn_-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hugh/SAT/env/include/site/python3.5/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sbgaxask/mysqlclient/
```

Can you please advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need python development libraries to build python modules:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpython3-dev
```

should take care of that for you.

But the recommended way to add this in Ubuntu would be to use the Ubuntu repositories. Thus, to install mysql bindings for python3, run

```
sudo apt install python3-mysqldb
```

This will install the bindings needed to connect to mysql from Python 3, and ensures that it will be upgraded along with other packages of your system. This is recommended, unless you specifically need a newer version, or the package is not available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: When virtualenv is an option, I don't think it's a good idea to use the repository. Installing a python package from the repository installs it globally, not just for the project you are working on, not to mention that you don't have any control over the versions installed. Your script will also be less portable.

Comment: I missed that it was a virtualenv. Anyway, you will have to install the python3 headers, which is required to build modules, even in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 6):

MySQLdb doesn't work with Python 3. if possible for you to switch from MySQLdb then I recommend you to use **MySQL connector Python**. Because it works with both Python 2 and 3 and it is **official Oracle driver of MySQL** for working with Python.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

if pip fails you can download the installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

i.e. installing MySQL Connector using DEB package [Refer this guide to download and install](https://pynative.com/install-mysql-connector-python/)

This module adheres to Python Database API Specification v2.0 (PEP 249).

Then Use `connect()` method of mysql connector python to connect to MySQL.pass the required argument to connect() method. i.e. Host, username, password, and database name

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install mysql-connector-python

sudo apt install python3-mysqldb
```